# my phone glaxey s4 had its screen crashed and Ive changed it and now it wont charge

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, charging

My Samsung Galaxy S4 keeps showing the message "Charging paused. Battery temperature is too low", whenever I plug the phone into a charger. I've tried using a different charger and even another battery but the message re-appears and the phone continues to not charge.

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: As the message states, your battery may actually be too cold to charge efficiently. Is the device in the correct operating temperatures? Most electronic devices won't charge if the room temperature is below 0°C. You could also try leaving it to charge for an extended period of time to allow it to heat up. I don't recommend trying to heat your device with a fire for example though, as this could damage it.

Comment: ^its not a temperature problem. I have seen a lot of people reporting and online sources suggest it being the thermistor lying near the charging port thats faulty. Ofcourse the real battery temp cant reach that low unless you live in Antarctica..... ofcourse I am not sure that it would be same for this case as well

Answer (score -2):

Reflash the stock rom using odin.
If it didn't work, change the power socket

Comment: and how would that exactly work to solve the problem ?

Comment: Sometimes the problem is related to software , or the socket is causing a problem